# SQL query doesn't seem to join correctly

Tags: mysql

I have two tables: `equipos` with names of football teams, and `calendario` with matches (jornadas). I need to get the matches of the jornada 1.

Example:
Real Madrid      -      Barcelona

Here is my query:

```
SELECT NOMBRE, NOMBRE FROM EQUIPOS 
LEFT JOIN CALENDARIO ON EQUIPOS.ID=CALENDARIO.ID_LOCAL 
    AND EQUIPOS.ID=CALENDARIO.ID_VISITANTE
WHERE JORNADA=1;
```

The first table is CALENDARIO and the second is EQUIPOS

[image: Calendario]

[image: Equipos]

Comment: Check that your join conditions are accurate. Your current join requires that ID_Local and ID_Visitante are the same, and this is never true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like :

```
SELECT local.Nombre, visitante.Nombre
FROM calendario
LEFT JOIN EQUIPO local ON calendario.ID_LOCAL = local.ID
LEFT JOIN EQUIPO visitante ON calendario.ID_LOCAL = visitante.ID
WHERE JORNADA = 1
```

And for your other question :

> Perfect. And if I have another table called ARBITROS with fields: ID
>   and NAME, I want to get the name of arbitros in every match??

There is the query :

```
SELECT local.Nombre, visitante.Nombre, arbitros.Name 
FROM calendario 
LEFT JOIN EQUIPO local ON calendario.ID_LOCAL = local.ID 
LEFT JOIN EQUIPO visitante ON calendario.ID_LOCAL = visitante.ID 
LEFT JOIN arbitros arbitros ON calendario.ID_arbitros = arbitros.ID 
WHERE JORNADA = 1
```

Comment: Perfect. And if I have another table called ARBITROS with fields: ID and NAME, I want to get the name of arbitros in every match??

Comment: Great, thanks. It's not important, but I tend to delete the dup comment afterwards too, just to remove clutter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do two joins with the table `EQUIPOS` (and they probably don't need to be *left* joins).

```
SELECT EQUIPO_LOCAL.NOMBRE AS LOCAL, EQUIPO_VISITANTE.NOMBRE AS VISITANTE
FROM CALENDARIO
JOIN EQUIPOS AS EQUIPO_LOCAL ON CALENDARIO.ID_LOCAL = EQUIPO_LOCAL.ID
JOIN EQUIPOS AS EQUIPO_VISITANTE ON CALENDARIO.ID_VISITANTE = EQUIPO_VISITANTE.ID
WHERE JORNADA=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT NOMBRE, NOMBRE FROM EQUIPOS LEFT JOIN CALENDARIO
ON EQUIPOS.ID=CALENDARIO.ID_LOCAL AND EQUIPOS.ID=CALENDARIO.ID_VISITANTE
WHERE JORNADA=1;
```

Your ON condition isn't possible because of the AND as your local team can't be the same as the visitor team ... You need to join 2 times the team table to do the condition on separated table